# IsSecureMode di.xml frontend / backend don't work

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, frontend, secure

Magento 2.0.10 and PHP 5.6.27

i have declare a etc\frontend\di.xlm en frondend whitch

```
<type name="Jbpevasion\Cartebleu\Block\Info">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item xsi:type="string" name="is_secure_mode">1</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

and in etc\adminhtml\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Jbpevasion\Cartebleu\Block\Info">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item xsi:type="string" name="is_secure_mode">0</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

but if i test

```
if (!$this->getIsSecureMode()) { .... }
```

i have the same for the admin et front ...
I've forgotten something?

thanks

Comment: Where do you run that test ? In the class you declared ?

Comment: in the class, and it's use in exemple line 105 Magento\Payment\Block\Info\cc.php

Comment: Raphael, tu es Français comme moi

Comment: yes I'm French too but it's an English only Website. M2 comes with a unit test for this field you can find it here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1ade3b769a937f19682bbbe4e51b6c956147952f/app/code/Magento/Payment/Test/Unit/Block/InfoTest.php#L65 maybe running it will help you find the issue

Comment: how to use this test mode? is there a doccumentation or examples?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in etc\frontend\di.xml you must add

```
<type name="Magento\Payment\Block\Info">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item xsi:type="string" name="is_secure_mode">1</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```